# MongoDB retrieve data with considering real-time insertion

Tags: mongodb

There are several objects in the collection like below.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c743e22d1b01269aa08922e"),
    "name" : "NAME",
    ...
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c743e21d1b01269aa08922d"),
    "name" : "EMAN",
    ....
}
```

And I want to retrieve some fixed number of data with this code.

```
var showPage = function(page){
    return db.orders.find().sort( { "_id": -1 } ).skip((page-1)*2).limit(2);
}
> showPage(1)
> showPage(2)
....
```

When using showPage(1) with 10 objects like [1, 2, 3, ..., 9, 10], I can get [10, 9], using showPage(2) can get [8, 7].

However, if someone inserts [11, 12] to the collection when between showPage(1) and showPage(2), showPage(2) retrieves [10, 9] that is different with desired result. [8, 7].

How can I modify this query that can retrieve desired result?

Answer (score 1):

Easy, just include the upper bound in your query:

```
 db.orders.find({"_id": {$lte: 10}}).sort( { "_id": -1 } ).skip((page-1)*2).limit(2);
```

Note, though, that this will not protect you from inserts in the middle of the range (were they to happen).